# Best way to find cancel and substitute match from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table which has all order information.

[image: Table]

Id is the unique key for the table and it's grouped by Order_Id (every order for the same product has the same Order_Id). The main thing is that if order is cancelled, it is recorded as a cancelled order (Cancelled? = True) and for following orders, it must have substitute orders. It can be an exact one-to-one match like Id 5 and 6 but it can also be one-to-many (Id 2,3, and 4), many-to-one, or many-to-many. As you can see, Id 1 and 7 are not part of cancelled/substitute match so should be excluded from the match.

My goal is to find cancelled/substitute match from the below table. It can be sql query or stored procedure. I was also thinking of having one another column - Parent_Id to record cancelled Id to substitue Id but it has to be updated from stored procedure as well.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use image for data, use formatted text, or better yet DDL/DML statements. Also show your expected results and attempt.

Comment: What's the desire output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validating (all) combinations is [potentially very hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) as this is essentially a [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). If you can add some limitations, then it often gets easier.

The solution below has the following limitations:

1. The order of the cancelled and substitute transactions within an `order_id` *cannot be mixed*. The solution adds up transactions within the `order_id` that come *directly after* the cancelled transaction in a running total (running sum). When the running total reaches the cancelled quantity, then the transactions are considered a match. Mixing the transaction order will mess up the running total and fail to find a matching quantity.
2. Within an `order_id` there *cannot be more than one cancelled transaction*. This would require a reset of the running total. This can be done, but will introduce more complexity to the solution.

Example of the mixed order I am referring to in limitation 1.

```
order id cancelled quantity
----- -- --------- --------
1     1  yes       100     --> 1 is cancelled
1     2  no        50      --> 2 is unrelated
1     3  no        100     --> 3 is the substitute for 1, but it does not come directly after 1...
```

**Sample data**

The imposed limitations are valid for the sample data: all substitute transactions come directly after the cancelled transaction and there are no multiple cancellations within a single `order_id`!

```
create table transactions
(
  order_id int,
  id int,
  quantity int,
  cancelled_date date,
  created_date date,
  cancelled bit
);

insert into transactions (order_id, id, quantity, cancelled_date, created_date, cancelled) values
(100000, 1, 100, null        , '2020-10-10', 0),
(100000, 2, 200, '2020-10-11', '2020-10-10', 1),
(100000, 3,  50, null        , '2020-10-12', 0),
(100000, 4, 150, null        , '2020-10-12', 0),
(100001, 5, 300, '2020-10-12', '2020-10-11', 1),
(100001, 6, 300, null        , '2020-10-13', 0),
(100001, 7,  50, null        , '2020-10-14', 0);
```

**Solution**

To see the running total in the results and better understand the final solution you can run this query.

```
with cte_cancel as
(
  select t.order_id,
         t.id, -- using id to get transaction order (alternative would be created_date, but then what if an order is created and cancelled on the same day?)
         t.quantity
  from transactions t
  where t.cancelled = 1
)
select c.order_id,
       c.id as cancelled_id,
       c.quantity,
       t.id as substitute_id,
       t.quantity,
       sum(t.quantity) over(partition by t.order_id
                            order by t.id
                            rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as qty_sum,
       case when sum(t.quantity) over(partition by t.order_id
                                      order by t.id
                                      rows between unbounded preceding and current row) <= c.quantity
            then c.id end as parent_order_id
from cte_cancel c
join transactions t
  on t.order_id = c.order_id
where t.cancelled = 0
  and t.id > c.id
order by c.id, t.id;
```

This produces:

```
order_id cancelled_id quantity substitute_id quantity qty_sum parent_order_id
-------- ------------ -------- ------------- -------- ------- ---------------
100000   2            200      3             50       50      2
100000   2            200      4             150      200     2
100001   5            300      6             300      300     5
100001   5            300      7             50       350     null
```

A minimal version of the solution that gives you just the matches would be the following:

```
with cte_cancel as
(
  select t.order_id,
         t.id,
         t.quantity
  from transactions t
  where t.cancelled = 1
),
cte_match as
(
  select c.order_id,
         c.id as cancelled_id,
         t.id as substitute_id,
         case when sum(t.quantity) over(partition by t.order_id
                                        order by t.id
                                        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) <= c.quantity
              then c.id end as parent_order_id
  from cte_cancel c
  join transactions t
    on t.order_id = c.order_id
  where t.cancelled = 0
    and t.id > c.id
)
select m.order_id,
       m.cancelled_id,
       m.substitute_id
from cte_match m
where m.parent_order_id is not null
order by m.order_id,
         m.cancelled_id;
```

Resulting in:

```
order_id cancelled_id substitute_id
-------- ------------ -------------
100000   2            3
100000   2            4
100001   5            6
```

A version with related quantities and dates could be this:

```
with cte_cancel as
(
  select t.order_id,
         t.id,
         t.cancelled_date,
         t.quantity
  from transactions t
  where t.cancelled = 1
),
cte_match as
(
  select c.order_id,
         c.id as cancelled_id,
         c.quantity as cancelled_qty,
         c.cancelled_date,
         t.id as substitute_id,
         t.quantity as substitute_qty,
         t.created_date as substitute_date,
         case when sum(t.quantity) over(partition by t.order_id
                                        order by t.id
                                        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) <= c.quantity
              then c.id end as parent_order_id
  from cte_cancel c
  join transactions t
    on t.order_id = c.order_id
  where t.cancelled = 0
    and t.id > c.id
)
select m.order_id,
       m.cancelled_id,
       m.cancelled_qty,
       m.cancelled_date,
       m.substitute_id,
       m.substitute_qty,
       m.substitute_date
from cte_match m
where m.parent_order_id is not null
order by m.order_id,
         m.cancelled_id;
```

Resulting in:

```
order_id cancelled_id cancelled_qty cancelled_date substitute_id substitute_qty substitute_date
-------- ------------ ------------- -------------- ------------- -------------- ---------------
100000   2            200           2020-10-11     3             50             2020-10-12
100000   2            200           2020-10-11     4             150            2020-10-12
100001   5            300           2020-10-12     6             300            2020-10-13
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d210fc148fb0c5b494fc2baafaef6abf) to see everything in action.